# How to Implement EBNF Repetition as Java Code?

Tags: java, parsing, bnf, ebnf

I am writing a simple recursive decent parser in Java that uses a lexical analyzer to split source code from a hypothetical imperative programming language (looks kinda like pseudocode) from a text file into individual tokens which are then examined to see if they follow the rules of an EBNF grammar. If the rules are not followed, the program outputs that a syntax error is present (not what it is or where it occurs).

Here is the EBNF grammar:

```
<program> -> program begin <statement_list> end
<statement_list> -> <statement> {;<statement>}
<statement> -> <assignment_statement> | <if_statement> | <loop_statement> 
<assignment_statement> -> <variable> = <expression>
<variable> -> identifier (An identifier is a string that begins with a letter followed by 0 or more letters and/or digits)
<expression> -> <term> {(+|-) <term>}           
<term> -> <factor> {(* | /) <factor>}
<factor> -> identifier | int_constant | (<expr>)
<if_statement> -> if (<logic_expression>) then <statement> 
<logic_expression> -> <variable> (< | >) <variable> (Assume logic expressions have only less than or greater than operators)
<loop_statement> -> loop (<logic_expression>) <statement>
```

And here is a sample program in the pseudolanguage without any syntax errors:

```
program
begin

sum1 = var1 + var2;
sum2 = var3 + var2 * 90;
sum3 = (var2 + var1) * var3;

if (sum1 < sum2) then
    if (var1 > var2) then
        var4 = sum2 - sum1;

loop (var1 < var2)
    var5 = var4/45

end
```

As you can see, every program must follow the `program begin` `<statement_list>` `end` format. Only the last statement does not require a semicolon at the end.

Right now, I have a basic program working. The lexical analyzer part has no issues since the output of the tokens for debugging purposes shows that they are all examined, but as for the EBNF parsing I only have it recognizing a statement as a simple variable (start small). I am unable to go any further because I don't know how to implement rules involving curly braces such as `<statement_list> -> <statement> {;<statement>}` (see above).

According to the Wikipedia page on Extended Backus-Naur form, curly braces indicate that repetition is optional. So in the case of this grammar, a `<statement_list>`, for example, is at least one `<statement>` optionally followed by any number of semicolon + `<statement>`. So if multiple `<statement>`s are present, all but the last have a semicolon at the end.

I am just unsure how to implement it based on my code. I know that you have to check if the token after a statement is a semicolon followed by another statement, but since this is a recursive decent parser and I have the methods returning a `boolean`, recursion would not work here which leaves iteration. However, since I implemented the lexical analyzer to delete the token from the buffer after it has been examined, this makes checking by iteration very difficult. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Here is my Java program so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SyntacticAnalysis {

    private static class Parser {

        // Parser has buffer -- which contains the source code as text -- it must read from
        private StringBuilder buffer;

        public Parser(File file) {

            // Reading from text file using simple scanner
            Scanner sc = null;

            try {

                sc = new Scanner(file);

                // Define buffer length as file length
                buffer = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());

                // Stops reading when no more text
                while(sc.hasNext()) {

                    // Token will be sequence of characters
                    String token = sc.next();

                    // Since token character sequence may contain characters such as ()+-*/=;
                    // We need to further break down token to separate special character and rest
                    // E.g. if(sum1<sum2) token will be further tokenized into: if ( sum1 < sum2 )
                    // This way spacing doesn't matter  
                    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(token, "()+-*/=;", true);

                    // Add tokens to buffer
                    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens())
                        buffer.append(tokens.nextToken() + " ");

                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

                System.out.print("File not found.");
                fnfe.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                sc.close();

            }

        }

        private String lexicalAnalyzer() {

            int i = buffer.indexOf(" ");

            // Lexeme will be from beginning of buffer (location of current token) to where whitespace is
            String lexeme = buffer.substring(0, i);

            // Delete lexeme from buffer since now stored in variable
            buffer.delete(0, i + 1);

            // Print what tokens are read for debugging purposes
            System.out.println(lexeme);

            return lexeme;

        }

        // Method for main
        // Returns program() since <program> -> program begin <statement_list> end is checked first
        public boolean analyzeCode() {

            return program();

        }

        private boolean program() {

            // Every program must have program followed by begin
            if (!lexicalAnalyzer().toLowerCase().equals("program")) return false;
            if (!lexicalAnalyzer().toLowerCase().equals("begin")) return false;

            if (!statementList()) return false;

            // Every program must finish with end keyword
            if (!lexicalAnalyzer().equals("end")) return false;

            return true;

        }

        private boolean statementList() {

            if (!statement()) return false;

            /* Repetition to check further statements goes here -- how to implement? */

            return true;

        }

        private boolean statement() {

            // Define statement as variable for now just as a test
            if (!variable()) return false;

            return true;

        }

        private boolean variable() {

            // Regular expression to determine valid identifier
            // [a-zA-Z] means starts with any letter
            // [a-zA-Z0-9]* means any amount of alphanumeric characters (0 - infinity)
            if (!lexicalAnalyzer().matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*")) return false;

            return true;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");

        String name = sc.next();

        File file = new File(name);

        Parser parser = new Parser(file);

        if (parser.analyzeCode())
            System.out.print("There are no syntax errors in the program.");
        else
            System.out.print("The program contains one or more syntax errors.");

    }

}
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: The `Scanner` here is completely pointless, a waste of both time and space. [tag:lexer] has nothing to do with your question. Repetition is simply s matter of looping in recursive descent. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of curly braces is to accept 0 or more items of the sequence they enclose. This is conventionally implemented as a loop, i.e., while the current token is one that can start the current sequence, process the sequence. Something in the lines of (beware, psudo-code ahead):

```
    while(FIRSTS contain lookAhead()){
      processCurrentBlock()
    }
```

What is this '`FIRSTS`'? It is the pre-calculated set of the tokens that may start the sequence that you are analysing at the momment. For example, `FIRSTS(;<statement>)` is ";".

`lookAhead` is a function in your lexer/scanner that returns the current token (without consuming it).

In a general way, the FIRSTS set of a sequence must not contain any of the tokens present in the FOLLOW set of that sequence. FOLLOW is the set of tokens that may come after that sequence.

Luckily, the FIRSTS sets of the three repeating blocks that you have in your grammar are distinct from their FOLLOW sets. Namelly, the FIRSTS of the sequence `;<statement>` is `[';']`, FIRSTS of the sequence `(+|-) <term>` is `['+', '-']`, and FIRSTS of the sequence `(* | /) <factor>` is `['*', '/']`.

It's just a matter of implementing that algorythm for each of these blocks.

Comment: This helps a lot! The concept makes perfect sense to me now. I know I needed to use a lookAhead() of some kind so the intuition was there but since this is my first exposure to parsers I didn't know how to go about it. Thanks man :)